# Facebook Graph API - get page feed + full event info?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Is it possible to, in 1 request, get the feed of a page but with the full event info?

As it is now, if a shared event is posted, you only get back the link to that event, no picture or title:

```
{
  "id": "xxx", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Community", 
    "name": "xxx", 
    "id": "xxx"
  }, 
  "story": "xxx shared xxx's event.", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/events/xxx/", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxx/posts/xxx"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxx/posts/xxx"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  }, 
  "type": "link", 
  "status_type": "shared_story", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Links", 
    "id": "xxx"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2013-06-19T10:05:50+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2013-06-19T10:05:50+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "xxx", 
        "id": "xxx"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to retrieve the events but you want to do it all at once with the feed because you want to retrieve the information on the feed anyway.

Before doing that, you must know that the feed doesn't contain all the events.... Once created, a **link** to the event is automatically shared on the page feed. It is only a reference, which can then be hidden. The event won't be displayed on the feed anymore even if it still exists.

#### Requesting two different objects at the same time

So, the feed doesn't have the events information and the events and posts (feed) are stored on 2 different tables. Therefore, you need to get the events **independently** from the feed:

1. The feed `/PAGE_ID/feed`
2. The events `/PAGE_ID/events`

And, as you wanted, Graph API allows you to do this **in only one request**:

```
/PAGE_ID?fields=feed,events
```

#### Additional fields

Note that either `feed` or `events` accept the `limit` and `fields` parameters. For example, `events` can be specified by:

```
events.limit(100).fields(location,name,owner,description,updated_time,venue)
```

Possible fields are given in [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/).

There is no way to get the "full info" at once. You will have to specify **each** field in the request. So, don't get the "full info", but just the information you really need.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, I tried this but it just gives me more feed posts, not extra event information such as the image unfortunately.

Comment: As explained at the end of my post, if you want the picture, you will have to request it.

Comment: Since it's a shared event, they are not included in the /events - checked via the graph api explorer.

Comment: I thought you wanted to grab the events created by the page of the feed. What you want **can't be done in only 1 request**. You'd need to do an FQL multi-query, but there is no way to get the object of the Facebook element that has been shared: **1.** there is no such field in the `Stream` table. **2.** in FQL, the ID of the event can't be parsed (`strlen()`, `substr()`) from the URL, [because the URL is stored in an array](http://bit.ly/10BV3P9). So, what you can do is to get the whole feed, get the events ID and get every event info separately. It won't be slower than doing a single request.

Comment: Thanks, I got the event IDs from the facebook URL (http://facebook.com/events/xyz/) included in each data element, and  at the end made 1 extra query to get the event information: select .. where eid in (eid1, eid2, eid3, ...)

Comment: If I do this query, is there a way to tell the difference between an event and a post? I'm not using an SDK.

Answer (score -1):

There is a post from Facebook addressing this scenario using multi-queries and FQL (Facebook Query Language). This will allow you to make multiple FQL calls in one request.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi

Comment: Getting the event information with FQL multiquery doesn't seem to be possible, because the eventid is stored in an attachment array in the stream table.
i.e.,
"attachment": {
"media": [
{
"href": "http://www.facebook.com/events/196571093854347/",
"alt": "",
"type": "link",
"src": ""
}
],
"name": "",
"caption": "",
"description": "",
"properties": []
}
the syntax attachment.media.href is not working, though the syntax
attachment.media is working but is of no use since the functions strpos() and substr() only work on string type and not on array.

Comment: There is no field in the stream table from where we can get that event id. Maybe facebook will provide the above functionality in the future. (Source: Dipak Y.)